# Searching functions that satisfy the differential inequalities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions

I'm trying to find two nonnegative continuous functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined on a bounded domain $[0,a]$ such that satisfies the next conditions:
\begin{align}
f_1(x) > & f_2(x),\quad\text{for } x\in(0,a), \\
f'_2(x) \geq & f'_1(x),\quad\text{for } x\in(0,a), \\
f_1(0) =& f_2(0) = 0.
\end{align}

On my attempts I try to use combinations between polynomials and exponential functions but I didn't get any positive results.

So I would appreciate any any suggestion, hint or a reference about differential inequalities or something related.

Comment: This is not possible $f_2(x) = \int^x_0 f'_2(s) ds \geq  \int^x_0 f'_1(s) ds  = f_1(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that,
$$
f_2'(x) \ge f_1'(x) \Rightarrow \int_0^x f_2'(t) dt \ge \int_0^x f_1'(t) dt \Rightarrow f_2(x)-f(0) \ge f_1(x)-f(0)
$$
you conclude  that there are no such functions.